# How can I initialize 2d array with a list of 1d arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I initialize 2d array with a list of 1d arrays?

```
void main()
{
    int a[] = { 1,2,3 };
    int b[] = { 4,5,6 };
    int array[][3] = { a,b };
}
```

Comment: Please note that in c++ `main` is required to have the return type `int` even if you never `return` from it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : my visual studio does not complain about it. I am using c++17.

Comment: Visual Studio won't complain about a lot of things. The same is true about all compilers and IDEs. First because the language does not require the compiler to diagnose every kind of error and also because many platforms provide default-on extensions that are not portable as best, and non-compliant at worst. It's a fact that the forms of `main` defined by the language all require the return type `int` in c++. One thing of note about `main` is that any platform can define any form of `main` they want, including ones that return `void` though they are by definition not portable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

raw arrays in C++ are kind of second class citizens. They can't be assigned and they can't be copied, which means you can't use them to initialize other arrays, and their name decays into a pointer in most circumstances.

Lucky C++11 offers a solution.  `std::array` acts like a raw array, but it doesn't have the drawbacks.  You can use those instead to build a 2d array like

```
std::array<int, 3> foo = {1,2,3};
std::array<int, 3> bar = {3,4,5};
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 2> baz = {foo, bar};
```

and if you have C++17 support you can leverage [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to get rid of having to specify the template parameters and the code simplifies to

```
std::array foo = {1,2,3};
std::array bar = {3,4,5};
std::array baz = {foo, bar};
```

which you can see working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e33515a262dca20)

Comment: It works in this case, but beware the uintuitive things that can (and occasionally have to) happen with this kind of initialization. If you didn't have `foo` and `bar` already, you'd have to write `std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 2> array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`, not `... = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 } };` (the latter does not compile)!

Comment: @MaxLanghof You could also use `std::array test = {std::array{1,2,3},std::array{3,4,5}}`

Comment: unfortunately CTAD doesn't work (yet hopefully) through a using directive to shorten the name :(

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::array`.

```
auto a = std::array{ 1,2,3 };
auto b = std::array{ 4,5,6 };
auto array = std::array{ a,b };
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87e6fbd64dccc2c5)

Answer (score 5):

The way you presented - not at all... You can have:

```
int array[][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

If you still need a and b, you could then have these as pointers:

```
int* a = array[0];
int* b = array[1];
```

or a bit closer to your original try: References to array:

```
int(&a)[3] = array[0];
int(&b)[3] = array[1];
```

This way, you could still e. g. apply `sizeof` to `a` and `b`...

Or the other way round: create an array of pointers

```
int a[] = { 1,2,3 };
int b[] = { 4,5,6 };
int* array[] = { a, b };
```

All these solutions presented so far have in common that both a and array[0] access exactly the same data. If you actually want to have two *independent* copies instead, then there's no way around copying the data from one into the other, e. g. via `std::copy`.

If you switch from raw array to `std::array`, though, you *can* have this kind of initialisation (with copies) directly:

```
std::array<int, 3> a;
std::array<int, 3> b;
std::array<std::array<int, 3> 2> array = { a, b };
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::array` is the way to go here, but if you want to stick to the means of the language (and not the standard lib), and your combined array has the same life time as its constituents, and if the data can be shared, you can have an array of pointers to arrays and say

```
int a[] { 1,2,3 };
int b[] { 4,5,6 };

decltype(a) *abArr[] {&a, &b};
// equivalent to 
// int (*abArr[])[3] { &a, &b };
```

Note that this is not a 2-dimensional array, and its elements are not integers.
But you can still range-loop through both dimensions because the pointers are true pointers to a fixed-size array (as opposed to pointers to a mere int as a result of array decay, which couldn't be range-looped).

Since the array elements are pointers it is necessary to dereference `row`:

```
for (auto const& row : abArr)
    for (auto const& e : *row)
        cout << e << " ";
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cff8ed0e69ffb436