# How can I join x 2-dimensional arrays into one 3-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have x 2-dimensional arrays and want to combine them in a 3-dimensional array

I have these two arrays for example (or more)

```
int array1[3][2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
int array2[3][2] = {{7,8},{9,10},{11,12}};
```

and the result should look like this

```
multi_array = {{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}},{{7,8},{9,10},{11,12}}};
```

but this doesn't work obviously:

```
int multi_array[2][3][2] = {array1, array2};
```

Does anything helpful come to mind?

Comment: Basically answered here (2D-1D case): [How can I initialize 2d array with a list of 1d arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54113882/580083).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to take a look at `std::array`. With this you can initialise like this

```
#include <array>
using mat2d = std::array<std::array<int,2>,3>;

int main(){
    mat2d mat1 {{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}};
    mat2d mat2 {{{7,8},{9,10},{11,12}}};

    std::array<mat2d,2> mat3d {mat1,mat2};
    return mat3d[0][1][0];
}
```

This code will return `3`. And the compiler is able to optimise all the matrix initialisation away.

This is the assembler with optimisation (-O3) turned on.

```
main:                                   # @main
        mov     eax, 3
        ret
```

[Here is](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Dteqjy) the working example.